# Maintaining dynamically computed values in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple **firebase** database: `/rides` is a list of simple objects like this

```
{
  car: "Toyota"
  minutes: 15
}
```

and I need to display sum of minutes of all the rides. The obvious solution is to load all the rides and calculate the sum. But if I have several hundreds of rides this is very slow, up to several seconds.

So it seems I have to maintain a separate field `/totalMinutes`in the database for this. But thus I will have to manually update `/totalMinutes` every time I add/remove/change a ride. Anyway this is not a big deal of work.

But what if I need to calculate total minutes only for a subset of rides? For instance only for "Toyota" cars or "Ford" cars? Manual maintaining `/totalMinutesFord`, `/totalMinutesToyota` now doesn't seem so easy.

So what is the correct way to maintain such dynamic values in **firebase**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firebase has no way to get automatically calculate values based on the data in your database.

So your two options are:

1. calculate the value whenever you update the data
2. retrieve all the data and calculate the value on the client

You already (wisely) decided that retrieving all data is not a good idea. Your users will be grateful for that.

So that leaves calculating the derived values whenever you update the data of a ride. I'm not sure why doing that for multiple values would be more difficult than doing it for a single value. It may be more code, but it's pretty much the same code:

```
var ride = { car: "Toyota", minutes: 15 };
ref = new Firebase('https://yours.firebaseio.com/');
ref.child('rides').push(ride);
ref.child('totalMinutes').transaction(function(current_value) {
  return (current_value || 0) + ride.minutes;
});
ref.child('totalMinutes'+ride.car).transaction(function(current_value) {
  return (current_value || 0) + ride.minutes;
})
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if I need to calculate totalMinutes for a subset of rides based on user input? For example only for rides, which minutes value is greater than something that user entered? I can't maintain pre-calculated values for all possible user inputs

Comment: That would only leave the option to download the relevant data and calculate it. But it will always be a strain on the device doing the aggregation and on the database.